# Syntax Error at Line * ) `in Ksh?

Tags: shell, unix, case, ksh

Im trying to execute the following code in Unix and getting the Above Error ,

Please Hep me to correct the code

```
SERVER_NM=`uname -n`
case $SERVER_NM in

  infad1)   export ETL_SYS=TST
         ;;
  infasa1)   export ETL_SYS=TST
         ;;
  infasb1)   export ETL_SYS=TST
         ;;
  infap1)   export ETL_SYS=PRD
         ;;
  infap2)   export ETL_SYS=PRD
         ;;
  infap3)   export ETL_SYS=PRD
         ;;
  infap4)   export ETL_SYS=PRD
         ;;
  *)        echo "No Dir";;
esac
```

when i execute this im getting

```
 unexpected4]: syntax error at line 5 : `in and im using !/usr/bin/ksh
```

Comment: adding 'export makes it as a constant character , can u say in detail with the above code

Comment: When I copy the code shown, I get a warning from `ksh` (on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks) that the back-quotes mechanism should be replaced by `$(...)` instead (formally, it says: ``xyz.ksh: warning: line 1: `...` obsolete, use $(...)`` where I called the script `xyz.ksh` and I ran it in 'debug' mode (`ksh -vn xyz.ksh`; no execute, verbose). When I run it, it says 'No Dir', which is reasonable.  The problem is not in the code you show, or you have a very screwed up `ksh` installed.

Comment: This is not the actual code and not the actual error message. Line 5 doesn't have a `*`, and a lone backtick looks like a truncated message (may be due to SO). Please be absolutely precise in describing code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance you have funny characters like carriage returns (`\r`) in your script?
Please run `od -c yourscript` to find out and if so, use a better editor that can display funny characters (vim) or `dos2unix yourscript`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export SERVER_NM=`uname -n`
case $SERVER_NM in
  infad1|infasa1|infasb1)  export ETL_SYS=TST ;;
  infap1|infap2|infap3|infap4)  export ETL_SYS=PRD  ;;
  *)        echo "No Dir" ;;
esac
echo $ETL_SYS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SERVER_NM="`uname -n`"
echo "${SERVER_NM}" | sed 's/infad1.*/PRD/;t;s/infasa1.*/PRD/;t;s/infasb1/TST/;t;s/infap[1-4].*/PRD/;t;s/.*/No Dir/' | read Tempo
export ETL_SYS="${Tempo}"
```

quicker maybe (depending of use of SERVER_NM)

```
export ETL_SYS="`uname -n | sed 's/infad1.*/PRD/;t;s/infasa1.*/PRD/;t;s/infasb1/TST/;t;s/infap[1-4].*/PRD/;t;s/.*/No Dir/'`"
```